# unable to create a text file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to learn the file I/O in python, I am trying following code to generate a text file in D drive of my computer with the statements written in the code but the compilation fails saying that the file 'I want to create' is not available which is obvious. How to create the file then?

```
file = open(r'D:/pyflie/text.txt',"w") 
file.write("Hello World") 
file.write("This is our new text file") 
file.write("and this is another line.") 
file.write("Why? Because we can.") 

file.close()
```

and the error shown is

```
  C:\Users\ssgu>python D:/pyfile/fw.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/pyfile/fw.py", line 1, in <module>
  file = open(r'D:/pyflie/text.txt',"w")
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
 'D:/pyflie/text.txt'
```

Comment: `pyflie` looks like a typo. I suppose it should be `pyfile`.

Comment: You have a typo in your `file = open(r'D:/pyflie/text.txt',"w")`. Should be pyfile

Comment: @mzjn  yes, it was a typo, I will be careful from next time. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will get such an error if one of the specified directories does not exist. In this case, `D:/pyflie/` does not exist yet, so it must be created beforehand. Then, your code should create and open the file normally. You can check upfront:

```
import os

if not os.path.exists(r"D:\pyflie"):
    os.makedirs(r"D:\pyflie")

file = open(r'D:\pyflie\text.txt',"w")
file.write("Hello World")
file.write("This is our new text file")
file.write("and this is another line.")
file.write("Why? Because we can.")

file.close()
```

Also, check for typos in the path name. Did you mean `D:/pyfile/`?

Comment: I hope you don't mind the edit ;) your answer is right...he needs to check first

Comment: The directory could be created in the program, as opposed to manually, using `os.mkdir()` or `os.makedirs()`.